# Documentacion Framework Kivy

Tags: android, python, apk

He estado investigado sobre el framework *kivy*, el cual esta dando mucho auge ya que permite hacer apk nativas. Alguien que fuera tan amable de brindarme algún link para documentarme.

Comment: La pregunta parece amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Aquí tienes la documentación https://kivy.org/doc/stable/

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Tu pregunta se soluciona haciendo una búsqueda en tu buscador favorito [(ejemplo de búsqueda en Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=documentaci%C3%B3n+kivy).

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una pagina en la cual te vendría bien empezar:
[Tutorial para empezar en *Kivy*](https://riptutorial.com/es/kivy)

Ademas aqui tienes toda su documentacion: [Documentacion Oficial de *Kivy*](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/intro.html)

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], si bien estos enlaces pueden ayudar; el solo apotar con enlaces se considera de baja calidad